# Drupal 6 - emfield is blank when logged out

Tags: 6, entities, nodes

I have created a content type and have added the Embedded Media Field. As i was logged in as administrator everything was showing ok but when I logged out and checked the page it was empty.

The text is showing ok but the enfield fields does not show the tumbnails of the youtube videos.

When i see the node while I am logged in as administrator everything looks correct but when I log out the corresponding emfields will not show up.

Has it to do with permissions? Because I have rebuilt them.

I check the php error.log and i see no errors.

Has anyone had any similar problem?

Comment: while you may have rebuilt permissions, have you granted permission to view this field to anonymous users at `admin/user/permissions`?

Comment: @Jimajamma yes that was it. I was confused because the guy that built the site and handed over to me have made some custom changes that wasn't easy to understand. You should write it as an answer to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd check that permissions are actually set to view this field.  If you go to `admin/user/permissions` you can see these as well as all permissions set on your site.